# AS3 - Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I keep getting the following error:

> TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.    at
>   FinalGame_fla::MainTimeline/pulse()
>   [FinalGame_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:183]

I have checked the code multiple times and can't seem to figure out what is wrong because the high score table still displays the correct entries.

Below is the code showing the variables defined and the code itself which is causing the problem.

**Defining Variables & Arrays**

```
var playerName:String="Anonymous";
var allScores:Array = new Array();
var nameBoxes:Array = new Array(mcScoreboard.player1, mcScoreboard.player2, mcScoreboard.player3, mcScoreboard.player4, mcScoreboard.player5); 
var scoreBoxes:Array = new Array(mcScoreboard.score1, mcScoreboard.score2, mcScoreboard.score3, mcScoreboard.score4, mcScoreboard.score5);  

var sr:SharedObject=SharedObject.getLocal("previousResults"); 

if (sr.data.allScores!=undefined)
{
    allScores = sr.data.allScores;
}
```

**Function for displaying high scores**

```
if (livesLeft==0)
{
    stopGame();

    mcScoreboard.visible=true;

    var playerScore:Object = new Object();
    playerScore["name"] = playerName;
    playerScore["score"] = totalScore;
    allScores.push(playerScore);

    sr.data.allScores = allScores;
    sr.flush();
    allScores.sortOn("score", Array.DESCENDING|Array.NUMERIC);

    for (var i=0;i<allScores.length;i++)
    {
        var obj:Object = allScores[i];
        *nameBoxes[i].text = obj["name"];*
        scoreBoxes[i].text = obj["score"];
    }
}
```

Flash says the line displayed second-to-last is causing the problem. But all variables and arrays have been declared appropriately so I do not understand where I am going wrong.

Comment: I'm assuming those asterisks are just there to designate to readers the line in question. Right?

Comment: Most likely,  `allScores` has more items in it than `nameBoxes`, so eventually in your for loop you get a null object returned because `i` is out of range.   Right before your for loop, add this line:  `trace(allScores.length, nameBoxes.length)`  if the first number is bigger than the second, that's your problem

Comment: If a null object was returned the error would be different. The error here makes it obvious that a dynamic property (no strong type) does not exist. obj['name' ] might not exist, nameBoxes[i] might not exist, check for both. Ultimately you might want to start working with strong typing and stop using timeline.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I fixed it by placing the code 'if (i==5) break;' as the first statement within the for loop.